# How to find a regex in re2 to search between strings?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, formulas, regex-greedy

I need to extract in RE2 syntax for Google sheets a query like below. The problems is i have to have everything between (including punctuation and amount of words) **"name":"** and **"},**

**NOTE: This is only one cell, there are many like this in my spreadsheet**

```
interests":[
{"id":"1","name":"West Bromwich Albion F.C."}, 
{"id":"2","name":"Tottenham Hotspur F.C."},
{"id":"3","name":"Arsenal F.C."},
{"id":"4","name":"Liverpool F.C."},
{"id":"5","name":"Sunderland A.F.C."},
{"id":"6","name":"EPL"},    
{"id":"7","name":"Southampton F.C."},
{"id":"8","name":"Manchester United F.C."},
{"id":"9","name":"A-League"},
{"id":"10","name":"West Ham United F.C."},
{"id":"11","name":"Chelsea F.C."},
{"id":"12","name":"Burnley Football Club"},
{"id":"13","name":"Barclays English Premiership"},
{"id":"14","name":"Stoke City F.C."},
{"id":"15","name":"Arsenal"},
{"id":"16","name":"Crystal Palace F.C."},
{"id":"17","name":"Football"},
{"id":"18","name":"Aston Villa F.C."},
{"id":"19","name":"Norwich City F.C."},
{"id":"20","name":"Leicester City F.C."},
{"id":"21","name":"Everton F.C."},
{"id":"22","name":"Arsenal Fans"},
{"id":"23","name":"Manchester City F.C."}]}],
```

my formula is

```
=iferror(REGEXEXTRACT(K98, "name\W:\W(.*?)\W}"), "")
```

but it returns only one in the column I need all the name of the football clubs in the same column or seperate.

i also tried using

```
=regexreplace(K98,"^interests\W+id\W\W+\w+\W+name\W:\W(.*?)\W},\W+id\W\W+\w+\W+name\W:\W(.*?)\W},\W+id\W\W+\w+\W+name\W:\W(.*?)\W}]}],$","$1, $2, $3")
```

to place in in the same column but returns the below (example)

```
interests":[{"id":"1","name":"Movies"},{"id":"2","name":"Entertainment"}]}],
```

b) when it cant find, so i put a regexmatch for each case but the (.*?) still reads the case <- how do i deal with the (.*?)

Comment: Check [*How to import JSON data into Google Spreadsheets in less than 5 minutes*](https://medium.com/@paulgambill/how-to-import-json-data-into-google-spreadsheets-in-less-than-5-minutes-a3fede1a014a#.7ku2if8fu).

Answer (score 1):

You can create 3 capture groups, then using regexreplace, replace the string with the second capture group like this:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A2,"({""id"":""\d+"",""name"":"")(.*)(""},)","$2")
```

[image]

and if you would like to use arrayformula, just change the reference to `A2:A` like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A,"({""id"":""\d+"",""name"":"")(.*)(""},)","$2"))
```

[image]

To get them all in one cell you can wrap the function with join such as:

```
=join(";",ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A,"({""id"":""\d+"",""name"":"")(.*)(""},)","$2")))
```

where I used the ";" as my delimiter - you can effectively use any delimiter you choose

Comment: i forgot to mention i need them all in the same cell

Comment: I updated the answer to include how to use the join function to do that